# Swift change UIImage in UICollectionViewCell from Array

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I have an array:

```
 var categoryImages = ["image1","image2","image3","image4"]
```

and this is how I am trying to get the images to change:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let myCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
    myCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    let size = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)

    var imageview: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: size)

    let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: categoryImages[indexPath])
    imageview.image = image
    myCell.contentView.addSubview(imageview)
    return myCell
}
```

However, this line:

```
let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: categoryImages[indexPath])
```

throws this error:

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[String]' with an index of type 'IndexPath'

Can someone help me: I would like images that are in the array to load into the UICollectionViewCells. Not as background images however, I would like them as images I can position etc..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `IndexPath` is not an `Int`, which you use to get value from index. `IndexPath` can be viewed as chain of `Int`. You need to get proper index from path using `section`/`item`/`row` (which one suites you should check yourself, it depend on details of your collection view).

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: categoryImages[indexPath.row])
```

Your categoryImages is an array, so you need to get the elements from it by their indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the array of images using the row: `indexPath.row`.